# get $.post to work with the validate plugin on multiple forms without seperate functions

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

On a fansite im doing http://yamikowebs.com/ee/ 
I have a few forms (2 atm). I used $.post to find out what form is being submited. submit the form and display that pages results where the form was originally with .html().

My next step was to use the validator which is working fine but im not sure how to put the 2 together.

`submitHandler: function(form){}` seems to be the setting for how its submitted. However, I can't get this to work with my `$.post` function or find out what form is being processed.

If I leave the defaults for validation plug-in if there no errors it will send you to the page. the ajax plug-in that it works with doesn't do what I want. Below is my `$.post` function

form validation:

```
//ajax post
$("form").submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();//stop from submiting
            //set needed variables
    var $form = $(this)
    var $div = $form.parent("div")
            $url = $form.attr("action");
            //submit via post and put results in div
    $.post( $url, $form.serialize() , function(data) 
    { $div.html(data) })

})
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#source is the validation plugin

Comment: So is the post actually not going through? Is the `submit` event handler not being called? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: i cant get it to work with the valation plugin. ie it ont work at all when i hit submit. if i take out defining the variables it will go to page with post. what i want is to post the information via ajax and diplay the results of the php page inside a div. in other words the php page is gonna to process the information and echo some html i want to put in place of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in thinking that `submitHandler` is the right callback to use. However, I ran into some interesting issues while using it with multiple forms (like you're trying to do). For example, in this code:

```
$("#form1, #form2").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert(form.action);
        alert(form.id);
    }
});
```

The `submitHandler` callback does not get supplied the correct parameter (it always gets `#form1`). I believe this is actually a bug in jQuery-validate (so I've filed it [here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/157)).

Anyway, a decent workaround would be to wrap the validate call in `.each()`:

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            /* 'form' has the correct value */
            var values = $(form).serialize(),
                $div = $(form).parent("div");

            alert(form.action);
            alert(form.id);
            /* Perform AJAX call here */
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/MmCXN/

Comment: Thank you. i have one small problem with it. something is bubbling... I have to hit submit twice for it to work.
     $("form").each(function() {
  $(this).validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
    /* 'form' has the correct value */
    /* Perform AJAX call here */
    $("form").submit(function(event)
    {
     event.preventDefault();
     var $form = $(this)
     var $div = $form.parent("div")
     $.post( form.action, $form.serialize() , function(data) 
     {
      $div.html(data)
     })
    })
   }
  });
 });

Comment: You need to make the `$.post` directly inside of the `submitHandler`: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/5KHuc/

Comment: if i do that then the default of going to the php page happens.
how would I prevent it from going to the php page?

 $("form").each(function() {
  $(this).validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
    /* 'form' has the correct value */
    /* Perform AJAX call here */
     var $div = form.parent("div")
     $.post( form.action, $form.serialize() , function(data) 
     {
      $div.html(data)
     })
   }
  });
 });

Comment: You have several syntax errors that are causing problems. **1.** Be sure to use semicolons at the end of statements. **2.** You haven't defined `$form` and you're using it in the function. Here's another example where the `POST` is done asynchronously (check Firebug to make sure): http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/Gj4xA/